# Make a form object in Django and run is_valid method

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a form object in Django views and run the is_valid() method on it.
I have tried

1.

```
form = LandingPageForm(initial={'user':user, 'name':"Shahrukh"})
```

and

2.

```
form = LandingPageForm(data={'user':user, 'name':"Shahrukh"})
```

but running form.is_valid() method returns false both the times,

I also tried

3.

```
form = LandingPageForm({'user':user, 'name':"Shahrukh"})
```

but is_valid() returned false, even though there were no errors.

In case 2 and 3 gave errors on the user field `"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."` which I am assuming is because user is a foreign key field and is rendered as a drop-down select field in the form.

What is the correct way of doing it?

I want to know how can we create a form object in Django views and run is_valid() on it

Comment: You are missing } in all 3 cases.

Comment: updated the question thanks

Comment: Please show `LandingPageForm`.

Comment: I have updated my question. The LandingPageForm is a model form with user as a foreign key,

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue. The error `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` was coming because it was expecting the id of the user and not the user object while creating the form.

As far as I discovered, here are my observations -

1. `instance={'data':value}` doesn't create the form object and fill data in it, hence `is_valid` always gave false and `form.errors` was also empty.
2. using the `data` parameter actually creates the form object.
3. Model forms of Models containing the foreign key field should be instantiated with the id of the object and not the object itself.